# Uri activation to itself

Tags: c#, callback, windows-8.1, protocols

I'm doing a oAuth authentification in a webview which call back my app.
It works fine on Windows phone 8.1, but in Windows 8.1 it shows a pop up (desired view) every time.

The app calls back it self when you register (protocolName://) and I catch it on "OnActivated" folling this page https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh779670.aspx

I added the called protocol in my manifest and I'm catching it fine.

The thing is that, on phone it works very well, but on tablet/desktop, it always shows this message[image]

My app is trying to open itself ...

The urls are catched from a login webview, this is why I'm trying to catch them with URI activation.

```
 protected override async void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
        {}
```